# I can't color my shapes. How to make it work?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

[image]
I can't color my shapes. I'm new and I don't know why it doesn't work. I need help.

Comment: I only can sélect the shzpe but i can't color the interiour

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! We need more information to be able to answer your question. Please edit the question and give us more information. At least tell us which application you are using (add the correct tag) and post a screenshot showing the entire screen instead of a photo of part of the screen. We probably need to see the entire shape and (depending on application) the layers and/or other relevant tool windows.

Comment: Based *solely* upon the cursor in the photo.. I'd guess Illustrator and Live Paint Bucket.. are the shapes (paths) selected? They need to be *selected* to use the Live Paint Bucket tool.

Answer (score 2):

I think Scott's right - based only on the cursor there, looks like a recent version of Illustrator and Live Paint.

And if so, Scott's comment ***is*** the *only correct answer* - you must ***select*** the items you're converting into a **Live Paint Group** - then it all works just as it says on the tin.

Two curves overlaid - both selected.
[image]

Live Paint tool hovering pre-click over selected curves.
[image]

First click defines them as a Live Paint Group.
[image]

Next click colours area beneath cursor with whatever is loaded in your colour palette.
[image]

Hope this helps.